# Load values of enum type into a combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, enums

Given the following enum:

```
Enum enumExample
  world
  oblivion
  holiday
End Enum
```

I can add its values to a list of ComboBox items like this:

```
combo.Items.Add(enumExample.holiday)
combo.Items.Add(enumExample.oblivion)
combo.Items.Add(enumExample.world)
```

Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to get a list of values for an enum then iterate the result:

```
For Each i In  [Enum].GetValues(GetType(EnumExample))
  combo.Items.Add(i)
Next
```

Or, as mentioned by @Styxxy:

```
combo.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetValues(GetType(EnumExample)))
```

Comment: Or even shorter, use the [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange.aspx) method to add the array (no need for looping it yourself).

Comment: 'AddRange' is a lot faster btw.

Comment: you can also use the `.GetNames` → `ComboBox1.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetNames(GetType(enumExample)))`

Comment: I really wish that people would stop providing answers that rely on implicit conversions. If Option Strict is turned ON, which it should be, this will not compile. Casting to an object array, as is suggested by Intellisense, causes a run time error.

Answer (score 15):

Why not just use:

```
Enum enumExample
  world
  oblivion
  holiday
End Enum

ComboBox1.DataSource = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(enumExample))
```

This is what I used and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Databinding ftw... ++