# How do I get a list of possible names/values from System.Net.SecurityProtocolType

Tags: c#, .net, enumeration

I wish to present a drop down list of the System.Net.SecurityProtocolType available on the server that the code is running from (The servers are different)

So I wish to do the working equivalent of

```
...System.Enum.GetValues(System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)

or

...System.Enum.GetValues(TypeOf (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType))

...
```

(both of these complain "SecurityProtocolType is an Enum type and cannot be used as an expression")

[image: Visual Studio error shown]

Ideally I'd like a VB.NET solution but would be happy with C#

Comment: `Enum.GetValues` takes a `System.Type`, not a type name.

Comment: VB answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419196/load-values-of-enum-type-into-a-combobox/14419229#14419229

Comment: Also there is generic overload - `var result = Enum.GetValues<System.Net.SecurityProtocolType>()`.

Comment: Please may I request that this question is re-opened? I have clarified showing why the answer and "question already has answers here" suggestions do not answer the question. I think this was closed without checking because on the surface it looks similar. This is especially true of the enum type into combobox/checkbox suggested questions. which are for user Enums, not system enums. The other suggested answer does not work in this specific case and I have provided a screen cap to demonstrate this. I do not ask questions unless I have exhausted other avenues. Please reconsider.

Comment: The keyword in Visual Basic is `GetType` not `TypeOf`. `Dim values = System.Enum.GetValues(GetType (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType))`

Answer (score 1):

As others said in comments, you need to use the type:

```
System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(System.Net.SecurityProtocolType))
```

that will give you the text values (SystemDefault, Ssl3, Tls, etc..). If you have custom display attributes you want to display, you need to use reflection, something like:

```
 @foreach (SecurityProtocolType type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SecurityProtocolType))) {
 var displayNameAttribute = type.GetType().GetMember(type.ToString())
 .First()
 .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
 var displayName = displayNameAttribute?.Name ?? type.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the responses. I have added to the original question that these suggestions give the same error, and also included a screenshot of the error being given for Michael G's larger suggestion.

Comment: Ok, seems like you are using VB.NET. "TypeOf is always used with the Is keyword to construct a TypeOf...". I'm not familiar with how to do it in VB.NET, you could try GetType(System.Net.SecurityProtocolType). link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/gettype-operator

Comment: Or you might need to use Object.GetType().. i.e 
System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.GetType()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-8.0

Comment: Or you might need Type.GetType, which appears to use a string representation:
ie. Type.GetType("System.Net.SecurityProtocolType");

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-8.0

Comment: Thanks Michael. You have helped me get to an answer. I can't accept that as the actual answer because it is not and also the question has been closed by the admins (too hastily in my opinion) - this is what works     For Each secProType As String In [Enum].GetNames(GetType(SecurityProtocolType))
    MsgBox(secProType)
Next